# Hyper-V: Why does allocating RAM also allocate disk space?

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, hyper-v, disk-space

System: Windows 10 Pro, Hyper-V

I have been trying to diagnose why my VM has been catastrophically running out of disk space in the middle of RAM-intensive computations.

In Hyper-V's "Settings for [YourVMsName] on [YourComputerName]" menu, I changed "Dynamic Memory" to `disabled` and specified 105GB of RAM as "*the amount of memory that this virtual machine can use*".

[image]

Upon starting the Virtual Machine, I see not only 105GB of RAM get reserved for the VM, but also 105GB of disk space, and I don't know why. This is a huge problem, because while I have 128GB of RAM, I only have 112GB of available disk space.

Here is before the VM starts up:

[image]

And after it allocates 105GB of RAM:

[image]

Is there any way to stop this behavior? So that I can use more RAM when "Avail RAM > Avail DISK"? And what is Hyper-V doing?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Microsoft post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2012/03/26/option-to-remove-bin-files-with-hyper-v-in-windows-8/) it is a feature to ensure there is enough disk space to hold the RAM. In the case of a problem, the contents of the RAM are simply dumped into the disk to record the virtual machine's state.

That post has directions to disable this feature. I'll repost below. Modify the following setting:

[image]